# The limit of a function that returns a set?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Can a function that returns a set ever have a limit? Is the notion of "limit" defined for functions that return sets?

I have in mind a function
$f: X \rightarrow Y$

Where $Y=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty a_{i}$,  $a_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Let's assume we've defined $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=S$, where $a$ is some element in our domain $X$ and $S$ is a set in the codomain of $f$. When we write $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=S$, what we're presumably saying is that as $x$ "gets closer" to $a$, the set $f(x)$ will get closer to $S$. However, this raises the question of what we mean when we say that "$f(x)$ is close to $S$". Note that $f(x)$ and $S$ are *sets*, and in the general case, there doesn't seem to be a sensible, natural way by which we could call two sets close.

Comment: Something like this can be found in measure theory, but for a countable domain (so talking sequences of sets.). I think in the book by Monroe, he introduces limsup and liminf, and then if these match, we say lim(An) = this common value, as integer n goes to infinity . Also your notation is confusing, for f seems real-valued. So maybe you mean $f:X \mapsto Y,$ or even $f:X \to 2^Y.$

Comment: Seems to me can do this if and only if you define metric on your collection of sets-- away to indicate when two sets are "close together" or "far apart".... although I can't comprehend the $Y$ you are asking about.  As written $Y$ is *not* a collection of sets but just a common everyday (countable) subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @311411 There is a notion of liminf and limsup for sets, but this doesn't really translate well for multifunctions. For example, the set-valued function $f(x) = \{x\}$ would be everywhere discontinuous by that definition.

Comment: Oh, is that what Mattia Ancis is talking about? Maybe OP should clarify. @forgottenarrow

Answer (score 1):

Functions that take multiple values are called *multifunctions* or *correspondences*. A correspondence $f$ from a space $X$ to a space $Y$ is written $f: X \rightrightarrows Y$. To keep things simple, we will call an ordinary function $g: X\to Y$ a *selection from $f$* if $g(x) \in f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Then one fairly standard notion of continuity is *hemi-continuity*.

A correspondence $f: X\rightrightarrows Y$ is *upper hemi-continuous* at a point $x$ if for any open set $V\subset Y$ such that $f(x)\subset V$, there exists an open neighborhood $x \in U\subset X$ such that $f(x') \subset V$ for all $x' \in U$. This implies that for any selection $g$ of $f$ such that $\lim_{x' \to x}g(x')$ exists, $\lim_{x' \to x}g(x') \in \overline{f(x)}$. Naturally, $f$ is upper hemi-continuous if it is upper hemi-continuous at all points in $X$.

A correspondence $f$ is *lower hemi-continuous* at a point $x \in X$ if for any open set $V\subset Y$ such that $V \cap f(x) \neq \emptyset$, there exists an open neighborhood $x \in U\subset X$ such that $V\cap f(x') \neq \emptyset$ for all $x' \in U$. This implies that for any $y \in f(x)$ and any sequence $x_n \to x$, there exists a selection $g$ of $f$ such that $g(x_n) \to y$.

A function is said to be continuous if it is both upper hemi-continuous and lower hemi-continuous. It's worth noting that if $f$ only outputs singletons (so it's a normal function), then continuity of $f$ as a correspondence is equivalent to continuity of $f$ as a function.

The wikipedia page for this is actually quite good if you would like further information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity.